# how repeat this animation forever

Tags: html, css, animation, repeat

please help me

how I can repeat forever this animation ?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Electrolize';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Electrolize'), local('Electrolize-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/electrolize/v2/DDy9sgU2U7S4xAwH5thnJ4bN6UDyHWBl620a-IRfuBk.woff) format('woff');
}

body {
 background: #310404 url(http://web-sonick.zz.mu/images/sl/red_texture.jpg) repeat top left;
 font-family: 'Electrolize';
}

.container{
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

h1.main,p.demos {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
 animation-delay: 18s;
}
.sp-container {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 0;
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
 background: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}
.sp-content {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: 1000;
}
.sp-container h2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 line-height: 100px;
 height: 90px;
 margin-top: -50px;
 font-size: 90px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 color: transparent;
 -webkit-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
 -moz-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
 -ms-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
 animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-1 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-delay: 0s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-2 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
 animation-delay: 3s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-3 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
 animation-delay: 6s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-4 {
 font-size: 200px;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
 animation-delay: 9s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 {
 -webkit-animation: none;
 -moz-animation: none;
 -ms-animation: none;
 animation: none;
 color: transparent;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span {
 -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
 -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 12s backwards;
 -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
 animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
 color: transparent;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 13s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 13s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 13s;
 animation-delay: 13s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 14s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 14s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 14s;
 animation-delay: 14s;
}
.sp-globe {
 position: absolute;
 width: 282px;
 height: 273px;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin: -137px 0 0 -141px;
 background: transparent url(http://web-sonick.zz.mu/images/sl/globe.png) no-repeat top left;
 -webkit-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 -moz-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 -ms-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=30);
 opacity: 0.3;
 -webkit-transform: scale(5);
 -moz-transform: scale(5);
 -o-transform: scale(5);
 -ms-transform: scale(5);
 transform: scale(5);
}
.sp-circle-link {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 bottom: 100px;
 margin-left: -50px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #fff;
 color: #3f1616;
 font-size: 25px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 -moz-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 -ms-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
}
.sp-circle-link:hover {
 background: #85373b;
 color: #fff;
}
/**/
@-webkit- 3keyframes blurFadeInOut{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 20%,75%{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeIn{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInBack{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.4;
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0.2;
  -webkit-transform: scale(5);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRotate{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 }
}
/**/
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeInOut{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 20%,75%{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeIn{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInBack{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.4;
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0.2;
  -moz-transform: scale(5);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInRotate{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 }
}
/**/
@keyframes blurFadeInOut{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 20%,75%{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  transform: scale(1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
  transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@keyframes blurFadeIn{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
  transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@keyframes fadeInBack{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.4;
  transform: scale(2);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0.2;
  transform: scale(5);
 }
}
@keyframes fadeInRotate{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 }
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
<div class="header">
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<div class="sp-container">
    <div class="sp-content">
        <div class="sp-globe"></div>
            <h2 class="frame-1">It's destroying the planet</h2>

            <h2 class="frame-2">It's mass, mechanized murder</h2>

            <h2 class="frame-3">You can stop it</h2>

            <h2 class="frame-4">Now!</h2>

            <h2 class="frame-5"><span>Save the planet.</span> <span>Love life.</span> <span>Go vegan.</span></h2>
<a class="sp-circle-link" href="#">Join us!</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/Sonick/pen/HthaI

thanks

Comment: What animation? Please include all relevant code in the question.

Comment: please edit your question and add your css to explain what you would like to achieve

Comment: please see the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put `infinite` on animation value

```
animation: sample 3s ease-in backwards infinite;
```

but you have to sequence your animation delay for each element. :D

```
animation-delay: 10s;
```

Comment: @iSaeed :) no no no. That's not how stackoverflow works. This might be downvoted or something but I gave you the idea. It's up to you if you will dig into it.

Comment: @iSaeed Actually, if I am creating animation that has a lot of sequencing. I will just use the GSAP TimelineMax. If you can use it. Go with it. It will make your work more easier.

Comment: thank you so much  , i add infinite and delay but not work :(
i want when animation done after 10sec again play

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of `animation` property goes as:

```
animation: name duration timing-function delay iteration-count direction fill-mode play-state;
```

so set `iteration-count` to infinite in all your animation sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Here a link to the basics of CSS 3 animations and examples of code
[CSS 3 Animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)